# Increasing user assigned 'administrator' privileges

Tags: privileges, windows-server-2012

We've just installed Server 2012 at our workplace, which in many respects is similar to Windows 8.

The issue is that a user has been created, and assigned as an administrator has a pathetically low level of access rights.

I'm finding that whilst running as this user, I still have to mark programs as 'run as administrator' which wasn't the case with our Server 2008 machine.

Is there any way to 'bolster' the prvileges of users created as administrators in Server 2012?